# File saving issue to public storage directory

Tags: java, android, file, save

I'm struggling with a file saving issue.

I have 2 features:

1. capturing photo and saving picture
2. adding picture to gallery

for the first part (file saving), I use

```
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    final File file = new File(getAlbumStorageDir(context, Settings.ALBUM),
            Settings.FILENAME_PREFIX + id +  + ".jpg");
    return saveDataToFile(byteArray , file);//writes bytes to file

    public static File getAlbumStorageDir(Context context, String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the app's private pictures directory.
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

for the second part, I'm coping file from 1 to public storage directory and making it available in gallery

```
File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), Settings.CAMERA_IMAGES_DIR + "/");
    if (!storageDir.exists())
        storageDir.mkdir();
    File copyFile = new File(storageDir, fileToCopy.getName());
    try {
        copyFile.createNewFile();
        copy(fileToCopy, copyFile);// writes bytes from one file to another
        Uri finalUri = Uri.fromFile(copyFile);
        galleryAddPic(finalUri, context);
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);

    }


public static void galleryAddPic(Uri contentUri, Context context) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, contentUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

In my case and most of other cases this works fine.
But some users are getting the following error:

```
Caused by java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:942)
   at com.testapp.utils.Utils.copyImageFile(Utils.java:311)
   at com.testapp.utils.Utils.savePhoto(Utils.java:420)
   at com.testapp.fragments.PictureListFragment$3$4.onAction(PictureListFragment.java:297)
   at com.testapp.views.PictureOverlayView$5.onClick(PictureOverlayView.java:145)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I checked, these users have write external permission.
StorageDir  in those cases looks like  /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/album. storageDir.mkdir() returns false and this directory doesn't exists.
Problem appears on this step:

```
copyFile.createNewFile();
```

I'll appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you first check if copyFile.createNewFile() returns true before doing anything.

Comment: Besides requesting permissions in manifest did you add code for Android 6+ to let the user confirm those permissions?

Comment: `if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Directory not created");
    }`. Do not blindly call mkdirs() as when the directory already exists you will get that log. Didnt you see that. Only call mkdirs() if the directory dies not exist. And if you cannot force that directory you should return null. And check for that null after calling the function.

Comment: `if (!storageDir.exists())
        storageDir.mkdir();`. Wrong! Check the return value of mkdirs. And display a toast and return null if false.

Comment: Problem is that  copyFile.createNewFile() throws exception and checking it for true wont help. But thanks for code improvement tip.

Comment: About permissions - i'm checking for write external storage permission before this code. Users did confirm write premission

Comment: Problem is not is first code part. I've put it there to explain where was initial picture saved.  Thanks for improvements idea, but not this part of code is the issue

Comment: Is there more appropriate way to add picture to devices gallery without copying it to public storage directory?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you are trying to store a file in an external storage. It seems the users that experienced that have no SDcard.

Comment: All devices have external storage. Which is used here. Has nothing to do with a removable micro SD card.